# Android Gingerbread NOT Catching Heap out of extermal memory (i.e. NOT Dalvik Heap Memory)?

Tags: android, unit-testing, out-of-memory, dalvik, robolectric

Update -- Pardon my verbosity below. As concisely as possible, this behaves itself:

```
try {
    mArrowBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(nam);
} catch(OutOfMemoryError e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "OUT OF MEMORY ERROR!!! ["+e+"]");
}
```

meaning that it throws an OOME when the external heap is exhausted. And I can catch that, and use it in unit testing.

This, however, misbehaves:

```
try {
    mArrowDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources(), mArrowBitmap);
} catch(OutOfMemoryError e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "OUT OF MEMORY ERROR!!! ["+e+"]");
}
```

meaning that it performs a really impressive suppuku. All I can do then is go through its pockets looking for loose change.

And for those with more time on their hands . . .

Problem: I have lots of bitmaps, some from Resources, some loaded externally.  I do some unavoidable manipulation on the device (i.e. stuff I can't do ahead of time, or do server-side).  Someplace during loading, I have at least one memory leak.  I'm chasing that, and pretending to be competent (and spending lots of time staring at DDMS/MAT).  Thanks to lots of comments on SO, I have done at least the basic research on bitmaps, especially on where they live pre-Honeycomb.  My app runs fine Honeycomb and forward.  It runs less fine on Gingerbread.  I can either

(a) ignore the memory leak since Honeycomb and forward will eventually reclaim the heap memory and, instead, try to get everybody on the planet to stop using Gingerbread, or

(b) isolate and squish the memory leak(s).

Option (b) seems better.

On Gingerbread, I understand that the native "backing" memory for my bitmaps (including the ones that the system mysteriously creates on my behalf when I load `.xml` or `Drawables`), all lives outside the Dalvik heap.  I further apprehend that the only thing on the Dalvik heap is a (relatively) small pointer to that native backing memory.  When I attempt to release resources, I must locate all the bitmaps I have created, and do a synchronous `recycle` on them.  My scheme for this, fwiw, is to "register" all my bitmaps into a simple vector when I create them, and then iterate the vector to recycle anything resembling a bitmap in native backing memory.

For this reason, I am untroubled by the various reports from the Dalvik heap that there is plenty of memory on hand, yet my `decode` calls fail for lack of memory.  In fact, I have dedicated some of my unit-test activities to pushing the boundary right to the edge to verify I'm not misbehaving (and, hopefully, do not do so in the future).  I do these unit tests using the "standard" Android unit test classes, since Robolectric can't "see" the heap to which I refer above.  Confession: I really like Robolectric much better, because it's about a zillion times faster.

That is a long way of getting to here:

When I intentionally run the native 'backing' memory off the end, by creating too many bitmaps, *most* of the time, I get what I expect: `OutOfMemoryError.`  I catch that Error and act responsibly (for very small values of 'responsibly').

When I prevail upon the `Drawable` calls (instead of the `BitmapFactory` calls, but sometimes both do this behavior), instead of an Error or an Exception, I get this in the `logcat:`

```
11-17 16:22:39.372: I/dalvikvm-heap(15069): Clamp target GC heap from 33.916MB to 32.000MB
11-17 16:22:39.372: D/dalvikvm(15069): GC_CONCURRENT freed 5K, 39% free 3701K/6023K, external 26854K/27965K, paused 2ms+2ms
11-17 16:22:39.402: D/dalvikvm(15069): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 5K, 39% free 3696K/6023K, external 26854K/27965K, paused 36ms
11-17 16:22:39.442: E/dalvikvm-heap(15069): 81796-byte external allocation too large for this process.
11-17 16:22:39.442: E/dalvikvm(15069): Out of memory: Heap Size=6023KB, Allocated=3696KB, Bitmap Size=26854KB, Limit=32768KB
11-17 16:22:39.442: E/dalvikvm(15069): Trim info: Footprint=6023KB, Allowed Footprint=6023KB, Trimmed=404KB
11-17 16:22:39.442: E/GraphicsJNI(15069): VM won't let us allocate 81796 bytes
11-17 16:22:39.462: I/dalvikvm-heap(15069): Clamp target GC heap from 33.912MB to 32.000MB
11-17 16:22:39.462: D/dalvikvm(15069): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 39% free 3696K/6023K, external 26854K/27965K, paused 3ms+2ms
```

I grok the clamping parts.  What I can't seem to untangle is how to detect the part in the middle:

```
11-17 16:22:39.442: E/dalvikvm(15069): Out of memory: Heap Size=6023KB, Allocated=3696KB, Bitmap Size=26854KB, Limit=32768KB
```

It does not appear to be either an `Error` or an `Exception.`  I can, of course, see this bad behavior manually by watching DDMS.  But I can't figure out how to isolate it programmatically, so that I can incorporate it into my unit tests.  It would, of course, also be nice to catch this behavior in my app, so that if a mistake does slip past my gauntlet of unit tests (it happens(way too often)) I might avoid the app unceremoniously barfing on its shoes.

Many thanks for the dedicated folks hereabouts who have explained the mysteries of Android memory with aplomb.  For anybody still reading, and puzzled by as I was by Android's entertaining memory structure, I heartily recommend starting here, with [Mr. Dubroy's excellent presentation](http://dubroy.com/blog/google-io-memory-management-for-android-apps/) -- Well worth watching, especially to the end of the audience questions.  Right at the end is a person off-camera who asks some exceedingly well-informed questions about these same baffling memory bits.

Any guidance here would be gratefully accepted.